# Cannot drag and drop radiobutton on groupbox

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

When I try to drag radiobutton and drop it on groupbox, the radiobutton never drops into groupbox but always behind it which makes radiobutton invisible because groupbox is in front. There is some option that groupbox is always on top. How to disable that so I can add radiobutton INTO/on groupbox and not behind the groupbox? Tried right click on groupbox - control - send to back but its not working.

Comment: Open the structure view window and drag the control into the right parent that way.

Comment: Hmm, excuse me? Haven't understood a single word.

Comment: View menu, then select structure view. Assuming a 21st century delphi.

Comment: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Structure_View_(IDE_Tutorial)

Comment: I apologize for another comment, may I please ask you for entire answer what to do? As you probably know there is nothing named ''structure view'' in View menu. The link which you just showed has no text.

Comment: may be try selecting the `group box` then drag n drop the radio button on the selected group box ..as without selecting the radio button is being dropped on the form and not the groupbox

Comment: That's because you are using an old Delphi. I can't remember what it's called in old versions and I've no idea what version you are using. I don't want to guess. Object TreeView sounds familiar from D6 days. Yes the link got mashed, but if I found it by a web search, so can you.

Comment: True David, will search for some quotes on particular link on my own. Thank you anyway.

Comment: I'm sure it's Object TreeView in Delphi 7 which you seem to be using and the answer referring to that is the right answer. The thing called Object TreeView is named Structure Pane in modern Delphi.

Comment: It is obvious that the link David posted got mangaled by the comment parser, and it is equally obvious that it can be fixed by appending a `)` character to the URL.

Comment: in Delphi 5 times i never knew about Sturcture View, ModelMaker and all that fancy stuff. I just striked Alt+F12 and directly edited DFM sources. In many-many cases just selecting the block of that button and Ctrl+K+V it into the proper parent would be fast and easy enough to not bother with GUI thingies. Of course would you be fuzzy, you can eaily corrupt DFM structure but that would most times mean that reverse Alt+F12 would be disallowed and you have Undo, version control and such :-)

Answer (score 5):

To put a new radio button on a group box, select the group box in the form designer, then select the radio button from the Component Palette and click on the group box.
If you accidentally put a radio button on the form or a different parent, you can delete it and add a new one, or use the Object TreeView to drag the radio button onto the correct parent.
I've created a [small video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vt_QfksWgaI) for you.

If by any chance your target parent is not a group box ([`TGroupBox`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.StdCtrls.TGroupBox)) but a radio group ([`TRadioGroup`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/Vcl.ExtCtrls.TRadioGroup)) you won't be able to add any child control to it - the radio group is designed to not allow any child controls. You can only define its radio buttons through the [`Items`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.ExtCtrls.TRadioGroup.Items) property.

Comment: If the parent is wrong, you can also Cut it, then select the desired parent, and then paste it. Don't copy it though, as it will not keep the same name etc.

Answer (score 1):

Try to Drag RadioButton on GroupBox in Object TreeView. Find it there by name. You can open a Object TreeView by pressing Shift+Alf+F11 by default.

Comment: Sk1nned thank you for reply but nothing from TreeView (in this case radiobutton) can be dragged inside/on groupbox, not even on form.

Comment: Drag it inside TreeView, not inside form

Comment: Sk1nned nothing (neither from form or from collection of elements) can be dragged inside TreeView, at least not in Delphi 7. I was asking how may I drag radiobutton and drop it ON/in the groupbox so it will be dropped on/it instead of behind it.

Comment: select RadioButton inside TreeView and drag it on GroupBox INSIDE Treeview :D

Answer (score 0):

Single Click on the GroupBox in the form designer (ie. on the form, not the component palette).

Then double-click on the Radio Button in the Component Palette.

The Radio Button should then be added to the GroupBox as a child component of said GroupBox.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you bother doing all these? Simply select a radiobutton and click it on the groupbox.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
CREATE GrpBox1 AS GROUPBOX
    Left = 295
    Top = 84
    Caption = "GrpBox1"

    CREATE RadioBtn1 AS RADIOBUTTON
        Left = 13
        Top = 25
        Caption = "RadioBtn1"
    END CREATE

END CREATE ' dont forget radio button is child of groupbox
```